# Template Classes and main

Tags: c++, class, templates, arguments, program-entry-point

I have the following class setup that trys mimicks a very basic stack.

```
template <class T>
class Stack{
    public:
        static const unsigned MAX_STACK_DEPTH =4;
        Stack();
        unsigned elements() const;
        Stack<T> & push(T &value);
        T pop();
        Stack<T> & show();
    private:
        unsigned element;
        T stack[MAX_STACK_DEPTH];
};

template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(){
    element=0;
}
/*Other class function definitions*/
```

My problem is that I'm getting the following error in main

```
1   IntelliSense: no instance of function template "calc" matches the argument list c:\users\nima\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\calcu\calcu\policalc.cpp    109 6   Calcu
```

Here is my main

```
int main(){
    bool run=true;
    while(run){
        if(calc(input()));
    }
}
```

here are the other two functions declarations

```
string input();
template <class T>
bool calc(string line);
```

Here is my calc function, It's not finished.

```
template <class T>
bool calc(string line){
    static T Ans;
    istringstream sin(line);
    Stack stack;
    for(string token; sin>>token){
        T t;
        if(parse(t, token)){
            push(t);
        }else{
            if(token==operators[i]){
                switch(i){
                case 1:{

                       }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is calc() declared as a template function, if it doesnt use T in its signature? I dont see where you use class Stack in main.

Comment: You provided stack template which is useless here. But didnt provide useful calc implementation.

Comment: i updated the post with the calc function. Does that help? :/ Sorry about that.

Comment: How will the compiler know what value of T you want calc called with?

Comment: Are you sure that you have only one error?

Comment: Thats the only error I'm getting atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `calc` function is a function template with parameter `T`, but that parameter isn't used by any of the function arguments – the only argument is defined as a `string`, regardless of what type `T` is.

Therefore, the compiler cannot defer `T` when you call `calc` like this:

```
calc(input())
```

You need to explicitly specify `T`, e.g.:

```
calc<int>(input())
```

(Of course, you should use whatever data type makes sense instead of `int`.)

Comment: I updated my post to show that I use T inside the function. Does that make things better? :/

Comment: @NimaGanjehloo No, unfortunately not. The type can only be deferred if it is used _as an argument_ to the function. Using it somewhere inside the function (or even as a return type, but not as argument) is not enough.

Comment: How would I go about making a variable that takes in any type inside the calc function in that case?

Comment: Hmmm... I think there is some misunderstanding here about what templates are. The type used for `T` must be known at compile time. (It needs not be known at the time when you write `calc`, but at the time you write the code that calls `calc` it must be defined -- either in the form of one of the arguments of `calc`, or by explicitly specifying it as in my answer.) Just think about what the compiler should do when it gets to the point in `calc` where `T` is used. How should it know what type to use?

Comment: Well that explains alot haha. Looks like I have to go back a few steps and rethink everything I'm doing. Thanks for the help.